# What type of grass is growing in our lawn?

Tags: identification, lawn, grass

I’m struggling to identify the type(s) of grass in our lawn. Grateful for any help. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Here's a helpful link to identify common grasses. 
https://www.scotts.com/en-us/library/grass-grass-seed/identify-your-grass